# Background view misplaced when comes to Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

*I have a `UITableView` with 2 sections (and only 1 row in each section.  The `UITableView` also has a header.  The Header, Section 0, Section 1 are all the size of the screen.*

I have a method that gradually changes the background alpha as you scroll:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height: CGFloat = scrollView.bounds.size.height
    let position: CGFloat = max(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0.0)
    let percent2: CGFloat = min(position / height, 0.99)
    alphaView?.alpha = percent2
    extraView?.alpha = percent2
}
```

Here's the code that sets up that `alphaView`:

```
    let overlay = UIVisualEffectView()
    overlay.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
    overlay.alpha = 1.0
    overlay.frame = self.view.bounds
    alphaView?.addSubview(overlay)
```

The only problem I'm having is that once the app is scrolled to Section 0 or Section 1 (so it will have a white background), **when the app is put into the multitasking background and then brought back into the foreground, the background is either non-existent or misplaced**.

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do for this?